# Docker MySQL Database JDBC URL connection Test Container

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, testcontainers

I have a Spring Boot 3.1 application with and am getting started with connecting to `test container` databases in Docker. I have not been able to figure out how to connect to the database with `application.properties` and `JDBC URL` string.

I believe test containers, whose life cycle are managed by Spring Boot are a different case to connecting to a regular and already running database in Docker.

So far I have installed `Docker Desktop` (windows) and have my application tests spinning up the database with a test class annotated with `@TestContainers` like:

```
@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ContosoApplication.class})
class ContosoApplicationTests {

@Container
public static MySQLContainer container = new MySQLContainer()
        .withUsername("root")
        .withPassword("secret")
        .withDatabaseName("contosodb");
@DynamicPropertySource
static void properties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
    registry.add("spring.datasource.url", container::getJdbcUrl);
    registry.add("spring.datasource.username", container::getUsername);
    registry.add("spring.datasource.password", container::getPassword);
}
```

I would now like to use a Docker database for when I run the full Application Context. As I understand it I need to change the JDBC URL string and add a gradle dependancy:

**build.gradle**

```
    implementation group: 'org.testcontainers', name: 'jdbc', version: '1.19.0'
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:tc:mysql:latest:///contosodb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=secret
## commented out next line for test containers
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

I have not used the CLI to setup my Docker containers. But it looks like:

[image]

And images:

[image]

Should the orange and blue parameters correspond to the image name as shown below or is that coincidence?

[image]

When I try with this setup I get stack trace: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Database name mysql not supported`.

Note that I would like to know if a new test (db) container (TC) can be started each time spring is run. Some information [here](https://programmerfriend.com/testcontainers-springboot-real-database) and [here](https://java.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/jdbc/).

Q: How do I setup Springboot application.properties to create a test (TC) MySQL database when I run the full application context?

**UPDATE**

For completeness here are the relevant parts of my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
implementation group: 'org.testcontainers', name: 'jdbc', version: '1.19.0'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-testcontainers'
testImplementation "org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter"
testImplementation "org.testcontainers:mysql"
developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'
...
...
implementation group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.28'
runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
...
}
```

Comment: Have you included the mysql test container dependency ?

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testcontainers/mysql/1.19.0

Comment: `implementation group: 'org.testcontainers', name: 'jdbc', version: '1.19.0'` (yes)

Comment: They are 2 different dependencies. 1 is for JDBC, and the other is for MYSQL. Need both

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testcontainers/mysql/1.19.0  <> 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testcontainers/jdbc/1.19.0

Comment: I have both:
`    implementation group: 'org.testcontainers', name: 'jdbc', version: '1.19.0'
    testImplementation "org.testcontainers:mysql`

Comment: I looked at `mysql` dependency POM. It actually has `jdbc` as a dependency, so you'd only need `mysql`.   The POM however does not contain a driver for MYSQL. you may need to also add
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysql/mysql-connector-j

Comment: The above is to do with the exception you got : `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Database name mysql not supported`

Comment: Its gradle not maven.

Comment: You can get the gradle dependency definition in the `Gradle` tab on mvnrepository. 
`implementation group: 'com.mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-j', version: '8.1.0'
`

Comment: Point is, that the TestContainer mysql package does not include a mysql driver - and if you haven't got a driver, you will get above exception

Comment: I have both 'org.testcontainers', name: 'jdbc', version: '1.19.0' and "org.testcontainers:mysql"

Comment: And `mysql-connector-j` , have you added it as your driver dependency ?

Comment: I had `mysql-connector-java` but tried `mysql-connector-j` - same error